# Having trouble understanding how to work TBXML

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xml-parsing

I followed the TBXML guide and it's been successfully installed into my code, but the guide they have doesn't make sense to me. I want to get some values from an XML document. An example they have of starting this process is:

`TBXML * tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.w3schools.com/XML/note.xml"]] retain];`

In NSLog, for me this returns:

`<TBXML: 0x4e3cc90>`

This example XML file contains the following:

`<note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>`

Could somebody give me a quick example on how from this XML file i would be able to extract the `<body>` of this? Their guide does seem fairly straight forward looking at it, but I just can't seem to make sense of it.

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/Guides_-_Loading_an_XML_document.html is their guide.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Andrew,

It appears that once you init TBXML with the xml file, as it appears you have, you then 'traverse' elements in the document using various API. I haven't tested this but it would appear in your example that "body" is a child of "note", therefore... first get the note element and from the root element and extract the body element from the note element.

```
TBXMLElement *noteElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"note" parentElement:rootXMLElement];
TBXMLElement *bodyElement = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"body" parentElement:noteElement];
```

You should be able to traverse on anything at this point.

-- Frank